# Why Do I get: TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given?

Tags: python, random

I have a problem with random.choice which I can't understand. I pass 3 arguments to the function which is allowed to have 4 (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), but it writes I am allowed to give only 2 and 4 were given.

```
def load_data():
    dataset = load_boston()
    num_samples = size(dataset.data, 0)
    test_set_sz = int(1.0 * num_samples / 10)
    tst_sub_inds = random.choice(range(num_samples), test_set_sz, False)
    data_test, label_test = dataset.data[tst_sub_inds, :], dataset.target[tst_sub_inds]
    trn_sub_inds = list(set(range(num_samples)) - set(tst_sub_inds)) 
    data_train, label_train = dataset.data[trn_sub_inds, :], dataset.target[trn_sub_inds]
    return ((data_train, label_train), (data_test, label_test))
```

The Error:

> tst_sub_inds = random.choice(range(num_samples), test_set_sz, False)
>   TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
>   Blockquote

What is the problem? Maybe it due to an old version of python?

Thanks, 
Eli

Comment: Show us how you do your imports. I suspect that you are calling Python's random library and not Numpy's.

Comment: I just made "import random"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you clarified in the comments, you are using `import random` which imports Python's random library.

You should use `from numpy import random`, which will import Numpy's `random.choice` which is the one that you expect.